# How can I change my output from DHCP Lease info to ScopeId "Name"

Tags: arrays, powershell, output, dhcp, scope-id

**Here is what My output looks like, It's just lease information where the host name is:**

```
IPAddress       ScopeId         ClientId           HostName       AddressState         
---------       -------         --------          --------        ------------  
10.10.10.10   99.99.99.99     11-11-11-11-11-11    AL10              Active
```

**Using this PowerShell script:**

```
$hostname = "AL10"
$locationArray = @()
  foreach ($Server in $DHServers){
        
        $scope = Get-DHCPServerv4scope -ComputerName $Server.dnsname  | Get-DHCPServerv4Lease -ComputerName $Server.dnsname | Where-Object HostName -like "$hostName*"
        
        $locationArray += $scope
}
 
$locationArray
```

**What I would like, is it just to output:**

```
ScopeID Name               
---------        
Name
```

**Goal is:** Provide a .txt of hostnames, find the corresponding DHCP Server leases, then output the "name" of the ScopeID like when using `Get-DHCPServerv4scope -ComputerName $Server.dnsname | Select-Object "name"`

Comment: Ok so what’s the actual question here?

Comment: How can I get my output to change to the ScopeID object "name" after passing my hostname through ```Get-DHCPServerv4Lease```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I used a hash table.**

```
$hashtable = @{} #create hash table

$i=0
foreach ($Server in $DHServers){
    $scopes = Get-DHCPServerv4Scope -ComputerName $Server.dnsname #get all scopes
    foreach ($hostname in (Import-Csv C:\script\Asset_List.csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty asset)){ #get hostnames from list
        foreach ($scope in $scopes) {
            
            if($scope | Get-DhcpServerV4Lease -ComputerName $server.dnsname | Where-Object HostName -like "$hostName*" ) { #compares the hostname to find which lease it is in
                try{
                $hashtable.add($hostname, $scope.name)# add keys, values to table
                }
                
                catch {
                    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
                    if ($ErrorMessage  -like '*Key in dictionary Already*') {
                         write-host 'Network issues could be causing process to take longer than normal' -ForegroundColor Green
                    }
                }
           
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

**Then I called it in my `PSCustomObject`**

```
[PSCustomObject]@{ #Rename varibles in data pull for output file
    Asset = $hostname
    Model = $System.Model
    SerialNumber = $BIOS.SerialNumber
    Location = $hashtable[$hostname]
    LastUser = $User
    MacAddress = $mac
    IpAddress = $IpV
    Status = "Online"
    }
}
```